# Jslt c out in a href

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, href

How should I write line:

```
<a href="User?id=<c:out value="${user.id}" />" >Profile</a>
```

correctly? It shoult give me something like Profile

My context:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.users}" var="user">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${user.login}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.lastname}" /></td>
    <td><a href="User?id=<c:out value="${user.id}" />" >Profile</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: There is no problem with the first line of code you wrote here, It's fine. If the id property of your **user** bean is not initialized with a visitor input, you can even drop the `<c:out>` tag and directly use the EL expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `'` inside `"` or vice versa

```
<a href="User?id=<c:out value='${user.id}' />" >Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[See image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGQ6p.png)

This code should do
`<td><a href="showDetails.jsp?id=${row.id}">Details</a></td>`

Comment: Please don't post a picture of the code, see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557