# C:Out is not working while calling javascript using href

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Can someone please tell me what is the error in my code? Without using the `c:out` I can display the output.

```
<a class="popUp" href="javascript:showMessage(<c:out value='${myHistory.userId}' />, <c:out value='${myHistory.userName}' />);">Click Here</a>
```

When I click the link `Click Here` nothing is happening. Please tell me how to use `C:Out` or `fn:escapeXml` in my code. Can also suggest me if there are other alternatives.

I have referred these links to write my code.

[Jslt c out in a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274443/jslt-c-out-in-a-href)

[XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: Did you checked the HTML code resulting of the compilation of the JSP ? You are talking about Xml, why ? (just in case or is it Xml ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got tags inside another tag, which is not allowed. You should use `${}` instead of `<c:out ... />`. I also suggest to use onclick to trigger the js function.

```
<a class="popUp" href="#" onclick="javascript:showMessage('${myHistory.userId}', '${myHistory.userName}');">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: it works now. Thank you @micaro